# Random letter generator not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Im having trouble figuring out how to write a script that basically saves a bunch of random letters to a .txt on **different** lines. What I have right now is:

```
import random
f = open("test.txt", "w") #clears current test.txt file
f.close()
f = open("test.txt", "a")
b = 0
def randomstring():
    global c
    valid_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    c = ''.join(random.choice(valid_letters))
    

while b < 10000:
    randomstring()
    f.write(c + "/n")
    b = b + 1

f.close
```

What this outputs is

> q/ne/ny/nt/nb/ng/nf/no/nu/ni/nr/nn/nh/nu/nr/ne/nx/nw/nr/nt/ns/nw/nk/nz/no/nb/nk/nh/nx/nj/nw/nu/no/nl/nv/nm/ni/nh/nd/nh/ng/nk/np/nd/na/no/nx/nn/ng/nb/np/nh/nb/nx/nj/nj/ne/nr/nb/nu/nr/nh/nj/nf/nw/ns/nl/np/nc/ne/nh/np/nu/nc/nw/nd/nt/nt/na/nk/np/nc/nm/nt/nt/nb/nw/nf/nf/nf/na/ni/n

What I want it to output is

> q
>
> e
>
> y
>
> t

ect. Thanks

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are escaping it incorrectly. The escape is as follows: `\n` not `/n`
Escaping is done with **backslashes** not forward slashes.

As follows:

```
while b < 10000:
    randomstring()
    f.write(c + "\n")
    b = b + 1
f.close

q
e
y
t
```

Also, since you are clearing the file everytime you write to it, why not just open it as `'w'` and write to it. That effectively overwrites the file, so it clears it and writes in it.

Comment: Depending on the intended output target, it's generally more flexible to use the OS EOL marker via `os.linesep`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a cleaned-up version:

```
# Assumes Python 3.x;
#  for Python 2.x, range should be replaced with xrange
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

OUTPUT = "test.txt"
NUM_WORDS = 10000
WORD_LENGTH = 1

def random_word(length, alphabet=ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(choice(alphabet) for i in range(length))

def main():
    with open(OUTPUT, "w") as outf:
        for i in range(NUM_WORDS):
            word = random_word(WORD_LENGTH)
            outf.write(word + "\n")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```